# Diagrams - sectors / circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

$OPQ$ is a sector of a circle with Centre $O$ and a radius $R$cm . $ABC$ is an Inscribed circle with radius $r$ cm . Given that angle $POQ$ = $ 1.047 rad $ , show that $ R = 3r$

I'm a little stunned when I saw " R = 3r " how should we show this when we don't know both r values ?

I tried finding value of $r$ by making Z the centre of the circle ABC , forming a right angle triangle OZC , but I have missing informations to find ZC which is $r$.

I suspect that I have an understanding problem here ... Can I get a hint on how to start ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S$ is the center of the inscribed circle. Then $\triangle AOS$ is a right-angled triangle with $Ô=30°$ and $S=60°$. Also $|AS|=r$, therefore $|OS|=\frac{r}{cos60°}$.
$$|OQ|=|OB|\implies|OB|=|OS|+r$$
Replacing |OS|, we get:
$$|OQ|=|OB|=2r+r$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the values. You have to show that whatever $R$ is then $r =  \frac{1}{3}R$ or equivalently  $R = 3 r$. Otherwise, you are on the right track by looking at triangle $COZ$.

Assume $R$ is some positive value, no matter what. Then draw the line $OB$. Since circle $ABC$ is tangent to the circle that determines the sector, $Z$ should lie on $OB$ (because if two circles are tangent to each other at a a given point then that point is collinear with their centers). Then what can you say about angles $\angle AOZ$ and $\angle COZ$? Now, can you find the angles of triangle $COZ$? What is $OZ$ in terms of $r$? What is $ZB$ in terms of $r$? Consequently, what is the ratio $\frac{|OB|}{|ZB|}$? Can you find now the relationship between $r$ and $R$?